# ListIterator has different behaviour at start/End

Tags: java, list, linked-list, iterator, listiterator

I wrote a very simple to get program, to refresh my skills on LinkedLists in case I need them.
Now, I stumbled on behaviour I did not expect. When I reach the end/beginning of my list and go forward/Backward, the same Element is displayed twice.

Here is how I thought it would work:

```
List =   [<Pointer>E1, E2, E3]
```

after next() call:

```
List =   [E1, <Pointer>E2, E3]
```

after next() call:

```
List =   [E1, E2, <Pointer>E3]
```

after previous() call:

```
List =   [E1, <Pointer>E2, E3]
```

but apparently, I have to call it twice to make the Pointer go back once. Why is this and how do I change that behaviour?

```
public class Playlist {

private LinkedList<Song> playList;
private ArrayList<Album> albums;
private Song currentSong;

Playlist() {
    this.playList = new LinkedList<>();
    this.albums = new ArrayList<>();
}

Playlist(ArrayList<Album> albums) {
    this.playList = new LinkedList<>();
    this.albums = albums;
}

void addAlbum(Album album) {
    albums.add(album);
}

void addSong(Song s) {
    if (albums.contains(s)) {
        playList.add(s);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Song unknown");
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Song s1 = new Song("song1", 111);
    Song s2 = new Song("song2", 222);
    Song s3 = new Song("song3", 333);
    Song s4 = new Song("song4", 444);
    Song s5 = new Song("song5", 555);

    ArrayList<Song> songList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    songList1.add(s1);
    songList1.add(s2);
    songList1.add(s3);
    Album a1 = new Album(songList1);

    ArrayList<Song> songList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    songList2.add(s4);
    songList2.add(s5);
    Album a2 = new Album(songList2);

    Playlist p1 = new Playlist();
    p1.addAlbum(a1);
    p1.addAlbum(a2);
    for(Album a : p1.albums){
        for(Song s : a.getSongs()){
            p1.playList.add(s);
        }
    }

    ListIterator<Song> listIterator = p1.playList.listIterator();

    p1.currentSong = p1.playList.getFirst();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    p1.showMenu();
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    ;

    while (!input.equals("q")) {
        switch (input) {
            case "s":
                if ((listIterator.hasNext())) {
                    p1.currentSong = listIterator.next();
                    System.out.println("Current song: " + p1.currentSong);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("End of playlist reached");
                }
                break;
            case "p":
                if (listIterator.hasPrevious()) {
                    p1.currentSong = listIterator.previous();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Start of playlist reached");
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input.");
                break;

        }
        p1.showMenu();
        input = scanner.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("Goodbye");
    scanner.close();
}

private void showMenu() {
    System.out.print("This is the menu.\n Your options: (s) - skip the current song.\n (p) - play previous song. \n (q) - Quit.\n +" +
            " Current Song playing: " + currentSong + "\n");
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#previous--) explicitly says that

> Note that alternating calls to next and previous will return the same element repeatedly.

Your pictures which you have drawn at the beginning (with the pointer) are correct, you have just probably interpreted them wrong. The `next()` method returns the element **on the right** of the pointer, and the `previous()` method returns the element which is **on the left** of the pointer.

Maybe the picture would look more understandable with one extra *comma*:

```
// list = [<Pointer>, E1, E2, E3] -- next=E1, previous=exception
assertEquals(E1, next());
// list = [E1, <Pointer>, E2, E3] -- next=E2, previous=E1
assertEquals(E2, next());
// list = [E1, E2, <Pointer>, E3] -- next=E3, previous=E2
assertEquals(E3, next());
// list = [E1, E2, E3, <Pointer>] -- next=exception, previous=E3
assertEquals(E3, previous());
// list = [E1, E2, <Pointer>, E3] -- next=E3, previous=E2
assertEquals(E2, previous());
// list = [E1, <Pointer>, E2, E3] -- next=E2, previous=E1
assertEquals(E1, previous());
// list = [<Pointer>, E1, E2, E3] -- next=E1, previous=exception
```

Comment: So I need to implement my own method that will check if I have reached the beginning/end and if so, it will call next() / previous () twice?

Comment: @InDaPond It depends on what you want to reach. If you want to return the last element only once, then of course you have to handle it on your own. Or you may just accept the logic of `next()`/`previous()` and change the expected behaviour of your program :)

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html):

> A ListIterator has no current element; its cursor position always lies between the element that would be returned by a call to previous() and the element that would be returned by a call to next().
>
> **next()**
>
> Returns the next element in the list and advances the cursor position.
>
> **previous()**
>
> Returns the previous element in the list and moves the cursor position
> backwards.

The difference between your illustration and the actual behaviour is that the cursor lies *between* elements, it is not a pointer to an element.

At the start, the cursor is before the start of the list. Calling next returns the first element, and moves the cursor forward. Now the cursor is between the first and the second element. Calling previous now will return the first element again, because that is the element before the cursor.